# How to set an object to only be viewable on certain interfaces

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I am running on Xcode 8 and before, there was a button that looked like:
w: Any h: Any and you were able to change the interface, add the object that you would want to show up on the interface, then it would only appear if that interface was selected (i.e., wouldn't show up in Portrait, but would show up in Landscape). In Xcode 8 there isn't that button that pulled up the grid but there is a "Vary for Traits" button, but it doesn't seem to work the same way, does anyone have any advice or help on this topic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen to device orientation change and hide/show the button accordingly.

In viewDidLoad add this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureYourButtonForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];
}
```

Then do whatever you want with the current status bar orientation. Note that you

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [self configureYourButtonForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
}

- (void)configureYourButtonForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{
    switch (orientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```